# Why is my CSS table displaying height for an element that has max-height of 0?

Tags: css

I have an outer `div` which I am displaying as a table, and and 2 inner `divs`.

The first inner div is floated to the left.  The second inner div has a max height of 0.

```css
.d-table {
       display: table;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }

    .float-left{
     float: left;
    }

    .hidden{
      max-height: 0px;
      overflow-y: hidden;
   clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<div class="d-table">
      <div class="float-left">
         hey
      </div>
      
      <div class="hidden">
        cool
      </div>
    </div>
```

Expected result is:

[image]

Actual result is:

[image]

The table is taking into account the div with a height of 0 for some reason.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs3q1j1s/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Seems causes due to non-zero `line-height` of the div and the `vertical-align: baseline` of the anonymous cell.

I would use `display: table-cell` in order to be able to style the cell with `vertical-align: top`

```css
.d-table {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.hidden {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-table">
  <div class="float-left">hey</div>
  <div class="hidden">cool</div>
</div>
```

If you need `display: table`, then you can't style the anonymous table cell, but you can reduce the space with `line-height: 0`.

```css
.d-table {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.hidden {
  line-height: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-table">
  <div class="float-left">hey</div>
  <div class="hidden">cool</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `.hidden` div is still part of the DOM and factors into the position calculations for the `.d-table` element.

Instead of `max-height: 0;`, use `display: none`. This removes the element from the flow of the DOM.

Comment: Yes, since table cells establish a block formatting context, clearance is probably not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `.hidden` element is theoretically being displayed correctly with a height of 0.
But then it has a `clear:both`, while the other div hass `float:left`, and their parents is displayed as table. 
This is the magic combo, confusing the height of the parent div.

The problem is: you first kind-of take the first div out of document flow. It is placed somewhere new, but still not really there (yes, floats are spooky as f***).
THEN you `clear:both` the second div, forcing it on a new line. The parent div (having forgotten all about the first div and the 18 vertical pixels it's taking up), can't have a height of 0 (because it's display-table), so it's given a minimum height of something-something.

There's really no other solution known to me than not using that combination. I would recommend actually hidding the hidden div (`display:none`).